# What's the best option for changing content inside a div?

Tags: html, web

I want to know what the best option would be for changing the content inside of a div.

Comment: Have you tried to figure this out by yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("yourDivId").innerHTML="your content";
```

Or using jquery

```
$("#yourDivId").text("your content");
```

Comment: And if i want to use html file inside this content?

Comment: Into the innerHTML you can put text as well as HTML tags, while using jquery you have to use html() instead  of text()

Comment: I meant: if i want to load a .html file inside div.. Still I must use this tags that you have mentioned last?

Comment: You should use an  iframe element and set its SRC attribute to the URL of tour HTML file but

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question

Comment: Yes! I just wanted to know which  way is the best. And yes, I forgot about iframe. Thank you!